# How to keep Facebook group post from collapsing

Tags: facebook-groups

I want to pin a long post at the top of my Facebook group to act as a menu. How can I keep it from collapsing?

Comment: By collapsing you mean getting rid of _see more..._ from the post?

Comment: Yes.  I want to see the whole post without seeing the see more prompt

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, this is how Facebook has designed it as of now. For a long post it show *continue reading..*.